# How to find specific array item inside for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find specific array item from `amount` according `**"1000,2000,3000|100,200,300"**` eg..,**(range|amount)** string by **input** amount

like..,

`--Range-- = --Output--
0 to 1000 = 0<br />
1001 to 2000 = 100<br />
2001 to 3000 = 200<br />
3000 onwards = 300`

I did for this

```
    var input = 3001;       // (test inputs 1000,1500,2200)
    var output=0;
    var str = "1000,2000,3000|100,200,300";
    var range = str.split('|')[0].split(',');
    var amount = str.split('|')[1].split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
        var checkRange= parseInt(range[i]);
        if(input<=checkRange){
            output=i!=0?(amount[i-1]):0;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(output)
```

this code is working fine only if `input` amount in between 0 to last array item`(range 0-3000, input is >=3000 )`, but if `input amount(<3000)` is greater than last array item(range) then  returning `0`

Please help to solve this stuff!

Comment: I don't think this is very clear... What should the for loop return? The index of a given item or the amount?

Comment: var input should be in between range

0 to 1000 = 0

1001 to 2000 = 100

2001 to 3000 = 200

3000 onwards = 300


(returns 0 or  100 or 200 or 300 according to range)

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

1. Your if condition was wrong .Change with `if(checkRange <=input)`
2. Because the `checkrange`  always lesser the `input`.That only its always zero.
3. Then remove the break statement.and declare the output  as `array`.
4. Then push each result value to array .Finally get the the last one value using `pop()`

```js
var input = 3001;       // (test inputs 1000,1500,2200)
    var output=[0];
    var str = "1000,2000,3000|100,200,300";
    var range = str.split('|')[0].split(',');
    var amount = str.split('|')[1].split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
        var checkRange= parseInt(range[i]);
        if(checkRange <=input){
            output.push(amount[i])
           }
    }
    console.log(output.pop())
```

Comment: It is working fine... thanks a lot for correcting my codes and helping

Comment: @Rakesh ...you are always Welcome

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative approach while checking if the value is smaller then the right range value.

```js
function getAmount(ranges, value) {
    var data = string.split('|').map(function (a) { return a.split(',').map(Number); }),
        index = 0;

    data[0].every(function (a) { return a < value && ++index; });
    return data[1][index - 1] || 0;
}

var    string = "1000,2000,3000|100,200,300";

console.log(getAmount(string, 1));    //   0
console.log(getAmount(string, 999));  //   0
console.log(getAmount(string, 1000)); //   0
console.log(getAmount(string, 1001)); // 100
console.log(getAmount(string, 2000)); // 100
console.log(getAmount(string, 2001)); // 200
console.log(getAmount(string, 3000)); // 200
console.log(getAmount(string, 3001)); // 300
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```